# Why does my form still submits even though the validator returns false?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, xhtml

I cannot seem to get this code to work. Any suggestions?
This forms should return false and thus not submit if the validation has failed. 
However, my code submits anyways regardless if the user failed the validation.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Student Feedback Form Validator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function userFocus()  
{
var x=document.forms["Login"]["userName"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("userName").focus();
  }
}
function javaScriptValidation()
{
validateUserName();
validatePin();  
validateSelection();      
}
function validateUserName()
{
var letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}$/;
if (!letters.test(userName.value)) 
  {
    alert("Invalid User Name");
    userName.focus();
        return false;
  }
}
function validatePin()
{
var code = document.getElementById("pinCode");
var letters = /^[0-9]{6,20}$/;
if (!letters.test(code)) 
  {
        alert("Invalid Pin");
        return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="userFocus()">
<form name="Login" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return javaScriptValidation()">
    <table summary="Form">
<tr>
    <td><label for="username">Your user name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" size="15" maxlength="20"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="pinCode">Your pin code:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="pinCode" name="userName" size="15" maxlength="20"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your method `javaScriptValidation` doesn't have a return value

Comment: `function javaScriptValidation()
{  
if (validateUserName() == false)
      {
        return false;
      }
if (validatePin() == false)
      {
        return false;
      }
if (validateSelection() == false)
      {
        return false;
      }
return true;
}`  This code here made it worked. Thanks for the direction. Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: Does that work? You can simplify to `function javaScriptValidation() {
 return (validateUserName() && validatePin() && validateSelection());
}`